# Do emotions dictate our destiny/faith?

Tags: nature-of-god, nature-of-man, human-body

What is the natural human behavior one can ask?

Many times people don't do good things because their emotions prevent them from doing so. It is good to be nice and friendly but if my emotions make me to be introvert I hardly can be social, one can say.

Many if not everyone suffer from social or other phobias which are regulated/controlled by our emotions. Atheistic person can be nice and friendly to people around him but practicing Christian can be quiet, shy and seen as unpopular because of this shyness he carries.

I was wondering if Jesus suffered with phobias, if he was shy sometimes or feared situations.

New International Version - Hebrews 4:15

> For we do not have a high priest who is unable to empathize with our
>   weaknesses, but we have one who has been tempted in every way, just as
>   we are--yet he did not sin.

This verse hints that he had to experience similar problems as every person has. But is this really the human natural behavior as God planned when he created a man? Was Adam and Eve shy and experiencing phobias before their fall? I guess not because the were shy and felt guilty after they disobeyed.

So the question is, can we see in the bible that Jesus was like Adam before his fall or we can see that He is more like us with the human faults and emotional difficulties and still sinless...

Also Is there some biblical evidence where Jesus didn't do something that looked good because he was shy at that moment?

I remember one passage where Mathew says:

> You weren't shy to come and visit me. Jesus said: No.

It's from the movie - Jesus of Nazareth.

Comment: I don't understand why you seem to think shyness and introversion contradict being "good and friendly."

Comment: that's not what I think. My questions are different. BTW - I know people who avoid doing good because they are shy or introvert and can't overcome the fear from being more social. You think people should be kept inactive in their lives because of that?

Comment: This is a general philosophy question.

Comment: this is so fundamental question that touches every single person and you want to close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Catholic Perspective**

The passions are natural components of the human psyche.<sup>1</sup> The term "passions" belongs to the Christian patrimony. Feelings or passions are emotions or movements of the sensitive appetite that incline us to act or not to act in regard to something felt or imagined to be good or evil.<sup>2</sup> The human person is ordered to beatitude by his deliberate acts: the passions or feelings he experiences can dispose him to it and contribute to it.<sup>3</sup>

<sup>1. [CCC 1764](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c1a5.htm#1764).</sup>
<sup>2. [CCC 1763](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c1a5.htm#1763).</sup>
<sup>3. [CCC 1762](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c1a5.htm#1762).</sup>

And In Brief [CCC 1774](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p3s1c1a5.htm#1774) has:

> Emotions and feelings can be taken up in the virtues or perverted by
>   the vices.

Jesus Christ being perfect God and perfect man had emotions and feelings, only in his case they were all taken up in virtue as he did not and could not sin.

You did not define what you mean by "shy" and therefore I cannot find from scripture whether Jesus was "shy" in the way you meant it.

Scripture speaks of Jesus:

1. [Marvelling](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%208%3A10&version=RSVCE).
2. [Being sorrowful and afraid](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2026:38-40&version=RSVCE).
3. [Being angry and grieved](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%203%3A5&version=RSVCE).
4. [Loving](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%2010%3A21&version=RSVCE).
5. [Being Compassionate](https://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?qs_version=RSVCE&quicksearch=compassion&begin=47&end=47).
6. [Weeping](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=John%2011:34-36&version=RSVCE).
7. Etc.

Comment: again the catholic answer is the best! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry about not answering your question fully, I actually just read the title and answered that :P In facing your emotions and feelings essentially you have started your path in finding the kingdom of God that is within you (KJV: Luke 17:21). In eastern religions this is referred to as liberation, enlightenment, or awakening. With that said you should pick up on two forms of meditation. The first being mindfulness meditation (preferably zazen), and the second being loving kindness meditation. Although both are Buddhist meditations, they do not go against Christian doctrine despite what others say. Mindfulness meditation will bring peace to the mind, and will reduce negative emotions such as anxiety. Loving kindness meditation will stimulate positive emotions such as self-esteem and compassion for others. Without inner stillness, you cannot be in tune with the "'still' small voice" which is the Holy Spirit.

Jesus did in fact feel the same emotions you and I have felt. The only difference between us and him was how he handled it. Jesus was constantly being tempted, but did not act according to those temptations both physically and mentally. So yes, Jesus felt shyness at one point, but it didn't control his actions. Second, man was made after Gods image. What you feel is not different what God can feel. You have a body, God has a body. You have a mind, God has a mind. You have a soul, and God has a soul. God gets angry, and we get angry. God gets sad, we get sad. God gets jealous, and we too get jealous. So by this pattern, it can be assumed that if we can get shy, then God to could experience shyness.

Comment: This answer would be a lot better if you could add references showing that this is a common understanding, and who teaches/believes it. Remember that "I believe it means..." isn't an acceptable answer, since this site isn't about personal interpretation.  See [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites) and [What makes a good supported answer?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/692/what-makes-a-good-supported-answer)

Comment: Also, "within you" doesn't seem to mean what you take it to mean. You is plural in the verse, and most translations say "among you" or "in your midst" and he was speaking to the Pharisees. His sense seems to be, as the NLT has it, "The kingdom of God is already among you."

Comment: I understand, I'm new to the site. I won't be able to dig through my sources tonight as it's midnight where I live. So your welcome to delete my comment and I may come back to it later :) In reference to Luke 17:21 (link #1: http://www.bible-researcher.com/luke17.21.html) (Link #2:http://syrcom.cua.edu/Hugoye/Vol12No2/HV12N2Ramelli.pdf)

Comment: No problem. And I hope you stick around and don't get discouraged! Being a newcomer to this site is hard work and can be frustrating with all the guidelines and junk, but they're there for a reason and I think there's lots to love about the community.

Comment: I don't agree with you. God has no emotions like people. It's us who assigns them to him. So no, God doesn't get angry. HE IS NEVER CHANGING...Malachi 3:6